# Noun for "the acquisition and communication of ideas"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a noun for the "acquisition and communication of ideas".  *Communism* would be a viable phonetic choice if it didn't have the political meaning. If there was a word meaning "idea-ism" then it would be a potential choice too.

For a sense of context, I'm trying to base a role-playing game on AD&D 2e (Advanced Dungeons and Dragons). There are schools of magic for wizards and one is known as *divination*. I wish to rename this school of magic to avoid ambiguity with clerics, who use divine powers for magic. The spells it governs include scrying and other communication-related abilities. I want to redefine its scope to include all spells related to messaging, communication, and the acquisition of ideas.

Comment: It doesn't mean what you want it to mean, so I won't post it as answer, but I'll point out the word ***conceptualism*** does exist.

Comment: Wizards are/use/go to the school of *computers*. What? They gather knowledge and disseminate it.

Comment: To anybody reading this, by "school of magic" I mean a classification of magic.  Sorry about the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider *impartation*, of which one sense is to communicate the knowledge of something  [[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impartation)] or more generally, the transmission of information [[Wordnetweb](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=impartation&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) at Princeton]. The *-ation* suffix may fit well with names of your other schools of magic.

Comment: *Impart* is not about *acquisition.*

Comment: @Kris, yes - compounds like 'school of importation and impartation' are hard to avoid when trying for all the meanings mentioned

Comment: This works for what I'm looking for.  Thanks to all for their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

> ***didacticism***:
>
> n 1: *communication that is suitable for or intended to be instructive*; "the didacticism expected in books for the young"; "the didacticism of the 19th century gave birth to many great museums"

[from WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006)](http://www.dict.org/bin/Dict?Form=Dict2&Database=wn&Query=didacticism)

Comment: *[Didacticism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/didacticism)* ordinarily has no connotation of acquiring ideas; rather, it connotes communicating them

Comment: It means teaching, of course: the propogation of ideas. One must have the ideas in order to communicate them; one must *know* in order to *teach*. What better possible analogy could there be for the *collection of ideas* than the creation of *museums*? ('Sides, OP is more interested in the communication aspect: if he could, he'd call the discipline -- which is focused on scrying and other communication-related abilities -- "*communism*". Also, and this is important: it *sounds cool*.)

Comment: “Propogation” is in a state of sin.  Aside from that, because of senses like  “Instructive or intended to teach or demonstrate, especially with regard to morality; Excessively moralizing; Teaching from textbooks rather than laboratory demonstration and clinical application” of the word *[didactic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/didactic#Adjective)*, *didacticism* is in at least some measure linked with pedantry.

Comment: Totally agreed on the pedantic sense of didacticism (almost inevitable, really). But I didn't get the part about a "state of sin" -- can you elaborate?

Comment: @jwpat7 "no connotation of acquiring ideas; rather, it connotes communicating them" was that, in fact, about your answer?

Comment: @Kris, Thanks. But, to be fair, my defense of *didacticism* against that charge applies equally well to *impartation* -- it is simply not possible to transmit something you have not first obtained. But more generally, we're playing a looser game, here: the idea is to come up with a *fitting* answer, something that adheres to the spirit, if not the letter; and, for that, "...-ation" carried the day, as it should.

Comment: @DanBron, “state of sin” ~ misspelled

Comment: @Kris, I often find it easier to criticize answers other than my own :)

Answer (score 0):

After all, what is **education** all about?

According to TheFreeDictionary.com:

> [education](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/education) (ˌɛdjʊˈkeɪʃən)
>
> 1. (Education) **the act or process of acquiring knowledge**, esp systematically during childhood and adolescence
> 2. (Education) the knowledge or training acquired by this process: his education has been invaluable to him.
> 3. (Education) **the act or process of imparting knowledge**, esp at a school, college, or university: education is my profession.
> 4. (Education) the theory of teaching and learning: a course in education.
> 5. (Education) a particular kind of instruction or training: a university education; consumer education.
>      [emphasis mine]

Answer (score -1):

It's the *Wizarding Bureau of Intelligence*. All sorts of spying, scrying, intel gathering, espionage, etc.

> Join us in the *Wizarding Bureau of Intelligence*

Comment: While it certainly has class, I made the mistake of forgetting to mention that a school of magic in the D&D world is not literally a school, but a classification.  I do like the title, though :)

Comment: It's still intelligence, even *classified* intelligence :).